# UISearchBar resigns first responder when trying to select UICollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uisearchbar

I have a `UIViewController` that functions as a sharing drawer, and slides up from the bottom of the screen.

I have a `UISearchBar` and `UICollectionView` below it, typing in the search bar updates the collection view without a problem.

When the search bar is active, I want to be able to select cells in the collection view. However, whenever I tap anything other than the search bar, the keyboard is dismissed. I am used to having to add a `UITapGestureRecognizer` or manually calling `searchBar.resignFirstResponder()`, but in this case I cannot figure out how to NOT dismiss the keyboard.

There are no other gesture recognizers on the view controller. Any ideas on allowing (multiple) selection of the collection view while the keyboard is present?

Comment: Did you implement `textFieldShouldReturn` method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@nayem's comment made me think of the `searchBarShouldEndEditing` delegate method. The search bar does send this message prior to `resigningFirstResponder` and I can return `false`. Problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

To unhide keyboard

```
self.view.endEditing(false)
```

are you looking for this?

---

as in case of

```
resignFirstResponder
```

you cannot pass a boolean to hide or unhide

---

---

We can also do this with following methods by always adding cancel button programmatically to search bar

```
    func searchBarTextDidBeginEditing(searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        searchBar.showsCancelButton = true;
    }
```

---

Also, should be trying by dropping an IBOutlet of the search bar as:

```
self.yourSearchBar.endEditing(false)
```

Note: yourSearchBar is the name of your search bar provided on dropping IBOutlet.

Comment: No...it seems the view controller is being sent that message automatically and i cannot stop it.

Comment: could you share screenshot of the hierarchy you have used in controller storyboard

Comment: @Raesu please check updated answer and allow me to dig-in more.